# numpy.random functions give constant values on manim

Tags: numpy, manim

I recently realized that random functions on **numpy** are always giving the same value when used in a `Scene`, as in this example:

```
from manimlib.imports import *

def r():
    return np.random.rand(5)

class MyScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        print(r())
```

will give over and over the same values:

```
manim foo.py MyScene -p
...
[0.5488135  0.71518937 0.60276338 0.54488318 0.4236548 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at **manim/manimlib/scene/scene.py** shows that there is a configuration parameter `random_seed` which defaults to 0.
When a `Scene` is created it calls `random.random.seed` setting the state of the random generator to this value.

To get your randoms again, set it to `None` as such:

```
def r():
    return np.random.rand(5)

class MyScene(Scene):
    CONFIG = dict(random_seed=None)
    def construct(self):
        print(r())
```